# How to pick the string after last underscore in Teradata sql

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I need to pick that portion of a `string` column in Teradata sql that appears after the last underscore. If the string is blank, it must return blank. The string can have multiple underscores.

```
input             output
abc_def_ghi         ghi 
ab_cd_ef_gh_ij      ij 
ab_cd               cd 
ab_11_22            22
```

How can I write to regex to capture the end section of such a string column?

Comment: What if there's no underscore, e.g. 'abc'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instr` can search backwards, `instr(col, '_', -1)` finds the last underscore:

```
substr(col, instr(col, '_', -1) +1)
```

Or a RegEx, which searches for characters between the last underscore and the end of the string:

```
regexp_substr(col,'[^_]*$')
```

Both solutions will return the full string if there's no underscore.

If you change the RegEx to `'_[^_]*$'` it returns NULL if there's no underscore.